# How to install redis 7.2 with igbinary and zstd compression on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, 22.04, redis

I tried to install redis by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:redislabs/redis
sudo apt update
```

Installed also:

```
pecl install igbinary
apt install libzstd-dev
```

But don't know how to add that to redis.